# А нужны ли интерфейсы?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

Делаю проект на архитектуре: controller ->service (use case) -> repository

Пытаясь следовать SOLID делаю для сервисов и репозиториев интерфейсы.

Однако в самой разработке это довольно мешает:

1) Нельзя быстро перейти на класс в IDE нажав на метод (переходит на interface, п.с. знаю можно прописать @var).

2) Банально больше кода за счет файлов интерфейсов.

3) На 95% уверен, что не будет массового жонглирования реализациями. Если вообще будет.

И вот назревает вопрос, а стоит ли? Если когда-то нужно будет сделать декоратор, жонглировать реализациями и т.д. - то просто отрефаторить и ввести интерфейс и опять же - только там, где он нужен.

Сейчас же у меня интерфейс ради интерфейса, усложение кода ради усложения. Принцип Kiss плачет в сторонке.

Comment: Вообще не могу понять как раньше без них обходился: интерфейсы - это многословно, но эта многословность окупается.

Answer (score 5):

Любая архитектура это прежде всего здравый смысл и вас под дулом пистолета никто не заставляет её делать. Если в вашем проекте интерфейсы мешают, не используйте их. Я думаю за это еще не сажают.

Comment: Но однажды могут прийти :)

Answer (score 3):

Думается что "Принцип разделения интерфейсов" (а скорее всего вы говорите об этом, раз упоминаете `SOLID`)  не подразумевает писать интерфейс под каждый сервис. Интерфейсы вы пишете по мере необходимости, а не потому что `SOLID` существует `I`.

> И вот назревает вопрос, а стоит ли?

Конечно же не стоит.

> Если когда-то нужно будет сделать декоратор, жонглировать
>   реализациями и т.д. - то просто отрефаторить и ввести интерфейс и
>   опять же - только там, где он нужен.

Все верно, там где нужен.

Comment: Нет, принцип "D" - инверсия зависимости, что нужно зависеть не от классов а от интерфейсов.

Comment: @Pavel формулировка более обтекаемая, нежели привязка к интерфейсам. Речь все же идёт о зависимости реализаций от абстракций. Является ли абстракцией интерфейс и только лишь интерфейс является абстракцией ? В симфони мы имеем дело с частным случаем DI - внедрением зависимостей и нам достаточно менять реализацию ежели чего, ну или как вы и сказали сами - добавить интерфейс при необходимости, а не всякий раз когда мы имеем дело с DI